# Interested in idioms similar to the theme of 集腋成裘

Tags: idioms

I'm interested in learning idioms that are related to small parts or actions eventually adding up to something bigger, or like idioms related to emergent property, kind of like 集腋成裘 (jíyè-chéngqiú).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I know a few:

- 聚沙成塔 - Gathering grains of sand can make a tower
- 滴水成川 - Gathering drops of water can make a river
- 積少成多 - small amounts add up to a huge amount
- 山大斬埋有柴 (Cantonese) - In a big mountain, you can gather firewood in small quantities and get a substantial amount of it
- 小數怕長計 (Cantonese) - Small sums will become a huge amount if you keep adding them up

An interesting 70's H.K ad song [小莫小於水滴，漸成大海汪洋，細莫細於砂粒，聚成大地四方](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hygRnB3_A8M)

> There's nothing smaller than a drop of water, they gradually added up to become a vast ocean; there's nothing tinier than a grain of sand, they gathered and became all the land in all directions

Answer (score 0):

My favourite one is from 道德经：

合抱之木生于毫末；九层之台起于累土；千里之行始于足下

You can check this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_journey_of_a_thousand_miles_begins_with_a_single_step) page. It has both Chinese and English version

Answer (score 0):

I recommend 多年媳妇熬成婆(a young wife will grow up into her mother-in-law over time).

Comment: The voice of experience?